# How to compute subtraction on same columns on different filters? Power BI

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

So i have a table that look like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWsfP.png)

I want to compute the difference between division under different filters
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISEKH.png)

I wonder how can i do this? The tricky part is that the filter is dynamic. the table content suppose to change when user click slicers

I'm expecting that i can get a column that shows the difference between division.
The user only need to click the slicer to filter the data set.
Be aware that multiple filters will be used.

I thought about join table, but that's not dynamic

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).